# Autohotkey, how to display a MsgBox that could cover the hole screen

Tags: autohotkey

I have lots of variables that I would like to display its value in a single msgbox, I thought about placing them in colums so they can fit, cuz otherwise the screen height is not enought to display them all, my subroutine goes something like this...

```
/::
Msgbox, varColummOne = %varColummOne% `tvarColummTwo = %varColummTwo%... `tnvarColummEight = %varColummEight%
. varColummOne = %varColummOne% `tvarColummTwo = %varColummTwo%... `tnvarColummEight = %varColummEight%
. varColummOne = %varColummOne% `tvarColummTwo = %varColummTwo%... `tnvarColummEight = %varColummEight%
. varColummOne = %varColummOne% `tvarColummTwo = %varColummTwo%... `tnvarColummEight = %varColummEight%
```

so there are like 34 lines of 8 columns, that's why I would like the msgbox's width to be the same width of the screen. But I have noticed that Msgbox's width has a certain pixel limit. How can I overcome that??? any workaround? perhaps a gui? could some AHK expert show an example??? thanx advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This toggles a ListView window when <kbd>/</kbd> is pressed**

```
/::
  global show := !show

  if !show
    Gui Alpha:Destroy
  else {
    Gui Alpha:New,,Debug
    Gui Add, ListView, r20 w700 -Hdr, 1|1|1|1|1|1|1
    LV_Add("", "row1col1", "row1col2", "row1col3", "row1col4", "row1col5")
    LV_Add("", "row2col1", "",         "row2col3", "row2col4", "row2col5")
    LV_ModifyCol()
    Gui show
  }
  return
```

**Screenshot**

[image: screenshot]

**Notes**

- `LV_ModifyCol()` autosizes the columns
- `-Hdr` option in `Gui Add` suppresses the header row
- `Alpha:` names the window so `Gui Destroy` knows what to destroy

Answer (score 0):

Tooltips don't seem to have that limitation.

**This toggles debugging screen when <kbd>/</kbd> is pressed**

```
var1=100
var2=101
var3=102
var4=103
/::
  show := !show
  ToolTip % show
    ?   "var1=" . var1 . "`tvar2=" . var2 . "`tvar3=" . var3 . "`tvar4=" . var4
    . "`nvar1=" . var1 . "`tvar2=" . var2 . "`tvar3=" . var3 . "`tvar4=" . var4
    . "`nvar1=" . var1 . "`tvar2=" . var2 . "`tvar3=" . var3 . "`tvar4=" . var4 : ""
  return
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: I have realized that using tab as separators looks very untidy, cuz sometimes the values are empty an then the columns loss their margins, Is it possible to display a table of 8 columns n 15 rows using GUI? thx advanced.

Comment: I used to read the AHK manual, but the manual part about ListView is just too big, Could you please provide an example??? thx advanced.

Comment: I posted another answer that uses ListView

Comment: please jimU tell me, it works fine, but what if I just want to add some vars but not in columns before all the columns, is it possible?? thx advanced.

Comment: Just add [Text](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GuiControls.htm) controls before the ListView to the dialog